# Creating a salary matrix

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to create a `matrix query` to display the job, the salary for that job based on the department numbers `20, 50, 80, and 90`, and the total salary for that job.

screen shot attached.

[image]

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Welcome to SO : Attach ur query. please visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: It is homework.
i have this:
SELECT JOB_ID JOB, SUM(SALARY) AS TOTAL,

     SUM(

        CASE TO_CHAR(DEPARTMENT_ID) WHEN  '20' THEN SALARY ELSE null END

     ) AS "Dpt 20",
     
     SUM(

        CASE TO_CHAR(DEPARTMENT_ID) WHEN  '50' THEN SALARY ELSE null END

     ) AS "Dpt 50",
     
     SUM(

        CASE TO_CHAR(DEPARTMENT_ID) WHEN  '80' THEN SALARY ELSE null END

     ) AS "Dpt 80",
     
     SUM(

        CASE TO_CHAR(DEPARTMENT_ID) WHEN  '90' THEN SALARY ELSE null END

     ) AS "Dpt 90"
     
     
     
FROM EMPLOYEES group by JOB_ID;

Comment: but now my total needs to be at the end because now it is placed after the Job.

Comment: Managed to get it right with e above code.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Assuming that is numeric  you can simplify the CASEes to `SUM( CASE WHEN DEPARTMENT_ID = 20 THEN SALARY END )`. No need for `ELSE null` becaus this is the default.